# Rails - How to save/log search queries to database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, search

I'm trying to make personal analytics for the search form on my website.

How can I go about this? My website is written using Rails, but I'm fairly new.

Basically, this - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-talk/DSkJMiu4W-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `SearchAnalytic` model to store that value:

```
class SearchAnalytic < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :value, present: true
end
```

With a migration like this:

```
class CreateSearchAnalytics < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :search_anlytics do |t|
      t.string :value, null: false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And then store the string searched for like this in your controller:

```
SearchAnalytic.create(value: params[:query])
```

To view the records, create a controller and a view like for every other `ActiveRecord` model and load the record with `SearchAnalytic.all`. Or if you want to group them, perhaps something like:

```
SearchAnalytic.group(:value).count.each |term, number|
  puts "#{number} times was searched for '#{term}'"
end
```

Comment: Okay. How can I be able to view it and go through the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Is 'search' an ActiveRecord-based model? If so, then just save it. (If not, and there's a reason not too, consider creating another AR model e.g. SearchTerm and capturing the query there.)